# Why is the data from messagingcenter not being sent over

Tags: c#, xamarin

Im new to C# and working in xamarin. i'm trying to load a user to be passed around the app to build a profile just for that user as thy use the app. I don't really care or optimization  right now I just want to know why this isnt working. Code looks like this.

Loading user from login

```
private async void LoginButton_Clicked1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user = new User();
    if (userNameEntry.Text == null || passwordNameEntry.Text == null)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("No info", "Please fill out UserName and Password", "Ok");
    }
    else
    {
        if (users != null)
        {
            if (users.Exists(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == userNameEntry.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                user = users.Find(x => x.UserName.ToLower().Contains(userNameEntry.Text.ToLower()));
                if (user.Password != passwordNameEntry.Text)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Password MisMatch", "Password don't match. Try again!", "OK");
                    passwordNameEntry.Text = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(FeedPage)}");
                    MessagingCenter.Send(user, "CurrentUser");
                    userNameEntry.Text = null;
                    passwordNameEntry.Text = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

trying to load that user somewhere else in app

```
public CoinPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.add = new ToolbarItem{Text = "Add", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary};
    collectionView.SelectionChanged += CollectionView_SelectionChanged;
    add.Command = new Command((sender) =>
    {
        this.AddCommand();
    });
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<User>(this, "CurrentUser", (sender) =>
    {
        user = sender; // -always null and can 't figure out why
    });
}
```

Comment: Yikes. It's very much not okay to directly match passwords to a textbox like this.

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to `Subscribe` **before** you `Send` a message

second, to pass an argument, use this syntax

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MyClass, User>(this, "CurrentUser", user);
```

where `MyClass` is the type sending the message, `User` is the type of the argument, `this` is a reference to the sender, `CurrentUser` is the message, and `user` is the argument

to subscribe

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyClass, User>(this, "CurrentUser", async (sender, arg) =>
{
  // do stuff
});
```

note that the types `<T1,T2>` must match between `Send` and `Subscribe`

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you can refer to the following code:

**1.Subscribe to a message**

```
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, object>(this, "CurrentUser", (sender, args) =>
        {
            User model = (User)args;

        });
```

**2.Publish a message**

```
        User user = new User { Name = "user1" ,age = 18};

        MessagingCenter.Send<object, object>(this, "CurrentUser", user);
```

**Note:**

Make sure you have subscribe to a message before publishing a message.

For more, check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center